# Flutter - Is there any way to restart iOS version programmatically?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have an flutter app and i used applifecyclestate.resumed to see if the app is running in the background and I used restart_app library to restart the app when it is in the background.This function worked in android but in ios it is not working

If you please tell is there anyway to restart the application in ios devices?

Here is the code

```
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      debugPrint('----------> app state resumed');
      Restart.restartApp();
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no point of doing that for iOS.

If you programmatically exit the app, your app will be rejected by Apple from the App Store anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, restarting an app in iOS is not officially supported due to Apple's limitations. However, you can try using the [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) plugin, which leverages native APIs to restart the entire app, including the iOS platform.